# What is the best game type to level up in?

Tags: battlefield-3

I'm not sure how I feel about the campfest that is BF3 just yet. I'm giving it an honest go, but I want to get some more weapons. What is the best game type to level up in or are they all mostly the same?

Comment: More weapons will not net you with better weapons. If that is what you are seeking, go for the TDM types, which will net you more kills and thus more loadout options for your equipment. A nice close to mid-range optics like the KOBRA will decide between a fast kill and a fast death.

Comment: btw. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41498/when-playing-conquest-where-are-all-of-those-points-coming-from/41658#41658

Comment: I level up here: http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/servers/show/3213e64f-0f87-43ab-abb3-4b67564aec7d/MM-METRO-MANIACS-3000-TICKETS-64-SLOT-ADAPT/ Plenty of XP to go around especially with Ammo- or Medkit. Especially because the tunnles are tight, people are always in range of your stuff. Ofc it brings other problems with it, like grenade spam. I have a positive K/D most of the time though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best game modes to level up in would be Conquest and Rush.

The reason these two are the best are because they contain objectives that are worth a lot of points.

The fastest is probably conquest as capturing a point (including neutralizing the point first) will net you 450 points (350 for assisting a capture) and there are many many points to cap per round. In addition, if you kill anyone while inside a flag's area of influence, you'll gain an extra 30 points per kill.

Rush is the second best as you can also get 600 points per objective (100 for arming, 500 for destroying. Only 200 for defusing) played, but they're aren't as many, and it's harder to get defends etc.

Comment: After last night, I don't know if I'll be playing it much longer. I appreciate the help, though. I'll give it some more time. Sounds like Conquest is kind of like CoD's Domination.

Comment: @Yatrix More appropriately, CoD's Domination is kind of like Conquest.

Comment: No, I said what I meant. Thanks, though. I prefer TDM and I think the spawn "system" has pretty much ruined the game for me in that regard. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: As I don't know enough about the game to pick the right answer on my own, I went with the most-voted.

Comment: The pointeless random spawning of TDM and DM also ruined this game for me. See you on MW3!

Comment: @SeanGallagher Yeah I hate the spawning in BF3 too. But just FYI, I've been playing MW3 quite a lot recently, and the spawning isn't that much better. It's better, but not by much.

Comment: @SeanGallagher The lag killed MW3 for me, I came back to BF3!!! Spawn fixes are going in today, I believe. Come on back if you're sick of laggy MW3 and campy maps. A lot of fun to go around.

Comment: Spawning still gives me headaches. Random respawns are direct in the vicinity of the enemy, and on-squad respawning sucks anyway.

Answer (score 13):

I would say go with Conquest. You can get +200 (+150 for assist) for neutralizing a flag, and +250 (+200 for assist) for capping a flag. In addition to the normal fighting points, and squad order points you would get. Over a long game - especially a hotly contested one you can get a good deal of point by going flag to flag.

Comment: You actually get 200 points for a neutralize, 250 for a cap. 150 and 200 are for assists.

Comment: ahh thanks, i'm almost always in a co-ordinated squad so i rarely cap alone.

Comment: I found myself as squad leader for several conquest games. Setting the squad objective to the most contested (or currently contested) flag gave lots of points for little effort. I assume it also benefited my squad who were also contesting those flags.

Comment: I agree with the above answer/comments. Just wanted to add my believe that these methods are best served as an Engineer, utilizing the various Tanks. Besides the above detailed points distribution, you can supplement with repairs.

Answer (score 3):

Conquest will reward you the most XP if you play the objective. If you can handle your gun well, you should try Team Deathmatch. In TDM, all the maps are cut off to a smaller area and every round is under 15 minutes. Also, if you are going for service stars for your gun, TDM is the best option as the matches are oriented on infantry combat. However, since you wish to unlock more guns, that would require you to level up your class. Conquest would be the best for gaining XP for your classes.

Answer (score 3):

This deviates from the question a bit, but if you like playing medic I've found picking a 64 player server with the Metro map is a great way to level up. You can get 500 XP or more just from the choke points by the esculators, per death.

Answer (score 2):

TDM is the best, since there is a lot of action, and it is easier to get kills, not to mention the fact that there are so many players on Battlefield 3 now, that you cannot capture a flag.

Answer (score 2):

TDM indeed is the best. Take a small CC map like Noshar Canals in TDM and just zigzag through the containers and kill. 32 vs 32 man 1000 ppm cant be achieved with other gamemodes, capping flags for points is for noobs. Just fckn kill.

Answer (score 0):

i would actully suggest noshahr canal with extended tickets back to back! i usually rack up over 7 thousand points even when not in the top three positions :D hope this helped

Answer (score -1):

Noshar Canals by far is the best map for XP. It's fast paced, instant kills and there are plenty of ribbons to be won. The only bad thing is the shortened time in which you can revive someone :(