# When playing Conquest, where are all of those points coming from?

Tags: battlefield-3

When playing Conquest, I stay pretty mobile and basically focus on deterring the enemy, capturing flags and destroying vehicles (my favorite). I typically end up with about 3000-4000 points with 15 or so kills. I never camp as it bores the piss outta me.

My question: I always see a guy that has 8000-9000 points, but he'll only have about 10 more kills. I'm sure he didn't capture 20 more flags, so is this person just camping our own flags, defending and just getting all the bonuses associated with that while handing out ammo or health? I've had a couple 7000 point rounds, but those are rare.

Comment: This question has been up 5 minutes. I'm shocked to not see an answer from Mr. Smooth yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a ton of ways to get a ton of points, as you might imagine.  Sometimes in these objective modes people "are playing a different game" as I like to say - they're just deathmatching with no real intent on completing the goals of the game.  This can drag out the rounds and make it more likely that you'll score tons of points.  I found a couple of videos of game replays where people had high scores though, and it seemed like they were focusing on capturing flags, using fast vehicles if available:

Comment: Yah, I hurl curse words at the screen when I'm calling for ammo (back button) and am being ignored or when I'm capping a flag and someone just goes right by. I turned my chat to friends only as it's not worth dealing with xbox live players 90% of the time. I just watch what teammates are doing - if they are going after a flag, I join in and help. My w/l is a 2.03, which I think is pretty good considering I always play on my own without a squad or a plan. =)

Comment: Playing for kills won't serve for the major objective much, but let's not forget, every kill is a ticket less for the opponent.

Answer (score 7):

Best non-kill related points:

**Objectives**

- **600** - m-com arm (**100**) and destroy (**500**)
- **450** - for flag neutralize (**200**) and capture (**250**)
- **350** - for flag neutralize assist (**150**) and capture assist (**200**)
- **200** - m-com disarm

**Squad support:**

- **110** - squad revive
- **30-150** - squad repair (**30** each repair)
- **30-150** - healing a squad-mate (**30** each heal)
- **20-160** - restocking a squad-mate with ammo (**20** each clip/grenade/rocket)

**Squad orders:**

- **as squad leader** - select objective to attack/defend, you get **20** each any time squad member follows that order (this can accumulate to quite a lot when whole squad participates).
- **as squad member** - **20** each time you follow order

**Team support:**

- **100** - revive
- **20-100** - repair (**20** each repair)
- **20-100** - healing a teammate (**20** each heal)
- **10-80** - restocking a teammate with ammo (**10** each clip/grenade/rocket)

Other:

- **150** - vehicle disable (**100**) + destroy (**50**)

There are much more, but much lesser value (spot, spawn on you etc).

Note for the squad/team support, it's what you get from one player. If you have bunch of them close together, you can get tremendous scores really fast.

Answer (score 3):

Travel in a squad and take flags. Flag captures and assists give you a rediculous amount of points. So between squad bonus points and captures you can reach scores like that easy. It is also realitive to how long the game is. Generally the more evenly matched the teams, the higher the scores. Kills really don't contribute much to ones score, you just need to kill in order to capture haha.

Comment: Yah, I only mentioned kills to note that the player wasn't like 40 kills ahead of me, which would easily explain 4000-5000 points.

Comment: Yeah, its really flag captures. You get a un reasonable amount of points per capture and if you spend the game tussling over a flag your points will fly up. It's like 300-450 points per full capture depending on if you're assisting or the main capture player. Also if you're in a sqaud mark the flag spots with the back button (If you're the squad leader). You get bonus points every time you follow the order or someone in your squad does.

Answer (score 3):

I often play Operation Metro and when I do I'm usually in the top three and sometimes I completely blow everyone away (by 10K points on a 1400 ticket map). Basically, I just play a medic. I only shoot when I have no other way to help the team. In those choke points, you can rack up a ton of revives and heals. I imagine other maps have other similar sweet spots for certain classes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are very good with tanks or choppers, infantry maps are so much easier to get high points in. I very rarely fall below 3rd overall on Metro or Grand Bazaar (which has BMP's and Humvees). Get a mate who is a good team player and dominate the battlefield :)

It's also a little bit about how you play. You said you don't camp, which is good, but neither do I, and I have a mate who gets in the 10000 point range every game. I don't know how he does it but I have never seen him away from an objective (he doesn't camp at them) or in a vehicle (other than for transport).

All I can say now is have a laugh with a mate and you will be surprised at how many points you can get without realising!